# Naming a list of dates (using IF)

Tags: arrays

I have to find the Group Week (4 Group Weeks) between dates and name them Grp1, Grp2 etc.

```
A               B
Date            Which Group   
2014/03/17      GRP1
2014/03/23      GRP1
2014/03/30      GRP2
2014/03/24      GRP2
```

I have tried

```
=IF(AND(A3>="2014/03/17"+0,A3<="2014/03/23"+0),"GRP1",IF(A3>="2014/03/30"+0,A3<="2014/03/24"+0, "GRP2"))
```

but, then it tells me array too long and it will not let me go up to 4 groups only 2.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, Either increase the array size unless it is dynamically being defined or break the groups into two, which you can further group into four. In this way, you will be making two groups per step however your problem will be solved.